# Change Test case type OTA API

Tags: c#, qtp, ota

I am using OTA API to create and execute test cases.
Is it possible to create custom test case types via OTA API?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** You must use a different API (and approach) to create your a custom test type. The OTA API does not provide a means for that.